# OpenMDAO v0.13: error only when trying to run optimization in parallel "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, openmdao

Please see the example added at the bottom, they pinpoint the error a little better than the original one.

I have been trying to get the attached code to run in parallel. This code is meant to mimic the structure of a larger optimization code that I am hoping to run on a large cluster. The error here is showing up in a few different scripts we have tried, one of which works in parallel unless connections are made to the component(s) initiated in the loop within the configure method from elements of an array. This example runs just fine in serial, but when I run the command `mpirun -n 4 python test2_forParallel_floats.py` I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/component.py", line 549, in run
    self._pre_execute()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/component.py", line 469, in _pre_execute
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/assembly.py", line 1701, in _setup
    self.setup_variables()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/assembly.py", line 1105, in setup_variables
    self._system.setup_variables()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 2387, in setup_variables
    super(DriverSystem, self).setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 2122, in setup_variables
    sub = list(self.local_subsystems())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/component.py", line 549, in run
    self._pre_execute()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/component.py", line 469, in _pre_execute
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/assembly.py", line 1701, in _setup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2_forParallel_floats.py", line 170, in <module>
    test.run()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/component.py", line 549, in run
    self._pre_execute()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/component.py", line 469, in _pre_execute
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/assembly.py", line 1701, in _setup
    self.setup_variables()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/assembly.py", line 1105, in setup_variables
    self.setup_variables()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/assembly.py", line 1105, in setup_variables
    self._system.setup_variables()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 2387, in setup_variables
    super(DriverSystem, self).setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 2122, in setup_variables
    sub = list(self.local_subsystems())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

    self._system.setup_variables()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 2387, in setup_variables
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2_forParallel_floats.py", line 170, in <module>
    test.run()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/component.py", line 549, in run
    super(DriverSystem, self).setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    self._pre_execute()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/component.py", line 469, in _pre_execute
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/assembly.py", line 1701, in _setup
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 2122, in setup_variables
    self.setup_variables()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/assembly.py", line 1105, in setup_variables
    self._system.setup_variables()
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 2387, in setup_variables
    super(DriverSystem, self).setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub = list(self.local_subsystems())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 433, in setup_variables
    sub.setup_variables(resid_state_map)
  File "/Users/thomas95/OpenMDAO/openmdao-0.13.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.13.0-py2.7.egg/openmdao/main/systems.py", line 2122, in setup_variables
    sub = list(self.local_subsystems())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone give me any insights as to why this will not run in parallel?

---

### Script

Note: The commented out `q` elements are added functionality we will need as well. Going one piece at a time here

```
from openmdao.main.api import Assembly, Component
from openmdao.lib.datatypes.api import Float, Array, List
from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import DOEdriver, SLSQPdriver, COBYLAdriver, CaseIteratorDriver
from pyopt_driver.pyopt_driver import pyOptDriver

import numpy as np


class component1(Component):

    x = Float(iotype='in')
    y = Float(iotype='in')
    term1 = Float(iotype='out')
    a = Float(iotype='in', default_value=1)

    def execute(self):
        x = self.x
        a = self.a

        term1 = a*x**2
        self.term1 = term1

        print "In comp1", self.name, self.a, self.x, self.term1

    def list_deriv_vars(self):
        return ('x',), ('term1',)

    def provideJ(self):

        x = self.x
        a = self.a
        dterm1_dx = 2.*a*x

        J = np.array([[dterm1_dx]])
        # print 'In comp1, J = %s' % J

        return J


class component2(Component):

    x = Float(iotype='in')
    y = Float(iotype='in')
    term1 = Float(iotype='in')
    f = Float(iotype='out')
    # q = Array(np.zeros(2), iotype='in', dtype='float')

    def execute(self):

        # y = self.y + self.q[0]
        # x = self.x + self.q[1]

        y = self.y
        x = self.x

        term1 = self.term1
        f = term1 + x + y**2
        # print 'in comp2 q = %s' % self.q
        self.f = f
        print "In comp2", self.name, self.x, self.y, self.term1, self.f



class summer(Component):


    total = Float(iotype='out', desc='sum of all f values')

    def __init__(self, size):
        super(summer, self).__init__()
        self.size = size

        self.add('fs', Array(np.zeros(size), iotype='in', desc='f values from all cases'))

    def execute(self):
        self.total = sum(self.fs)
        print 'In summer, fs = %s and total = %s' % (self.fs, self.total)


class assembly(Assembly):

    x = Float(iotype='in')
    y = Float(iotype='in')
    total = Float(iotype='out')

    def __init__(self, size):

        super(assembly, self).__init__()

        self.size = size
        for i in range(0, size):
            self.add('a_vals_%d' % i, Float(iotype='in'))
            # self.add('q_%d' % i, Array(np.zeros(2), iotype='in', dtype='float'))
            a = str()
            exec("a = self.a_vals_%d" % i)
            print 'in init, a_vals_%d = %s' % (i, a)

        self.add('fs', Array(np.zeros(size), iotype='out', dtype='float'))
        print 'in init, fs = %s' % self.fs

    def configure(self):

        self.add('driver', SLSQPdriver())
        # self.add('driver', pyOptDriver())
        # self.driver.optimizer = 'SNOPT'
        # self.driver.pyopt_diff = True

        #create this first, so we can connect to it
        self.add('summer', summer(size=self.size))
        self.connect('summer.total', 'total')

        for i in range(0, self.size):
            a = str()
            exec("a = self.a_vals_%d" % i)
            print 'in configure, a_vals_%d = %s' % (i, a)


        # create instances of components
        for i in range(0, self.size):
            c1 = self.add('comp1_%d' % i, component1())
            c1.missing_deriv_policy = 'assume_zero'

            c2 = self.add('comp2_%d'%i, component2())
            self.connect('a_vals_%d' % i, 'comp1_%d.a' % i)
            self.connect('x', ['comp1_%d.x' % i, 'comp2_%d.x' % i])
            self.connect('y', ['comp1_%d.y' % i, 'comp2_%d.y' % i])
            self.connect('comp1_%d.term1' % i, 'comp2_%d.term1' % i)
            # self.connect('q_%d' % i, 'comp2_%d.q' % i)

            self.connect('comp2_%d.f' % i, 'summer.fs[%d]' % i)

            self.driver.workflow.add(['comp1_%d' % i, 'comp2_%d' % i])

        # self.connect('summer.fs[:]', 'fs[:]')
        self.driver.workflow.add(['summer'])

        # set up main driver (optimizer)
        self.driver.iprint = 1
        self.driver.maxiter = 100
        self.driver.accuracy = 1.0e-6
        self.driver.add_parameter('x', low=-5., high=5.)
        self.driver.add_parameter('y', low=0., high=5.)
        # for i in range(0, self.size):
        #     self.driver.add_parameter('q_%d' % i, low=0., high=5.)
        self.driver.add_objective('summer.total')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ the result should be -1 at (x, y) = (-0.5, 0) """

    import time
    from openmdao.main.api import set_as_top
    a_vals = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1.])
    test = set_as_top(assembly(size=len(a_vals)))
    # test.a_vals = a_vals
    # print 'in main, test.a_vals = %s, test.fs = %s' % (test.a_vals, test.fs)
    test.x = 2.
    test.y = 5
    # q = np.tile(np.arange(1., 3.), (4, 1))
    for i in range(0, len(a_vals)):
        exec('test.a_vals_%d = a_vals[%d]' % (i, i))
    #     exec('test.q_%d = q[%d]' % (i, i))
    #     exec('print test.q_%d' % i)
        a = str()
        exec("a = test.a_vals_%d" % i)
        print 'in main, a_vals_%d = %s' % (i, a)

    tt = time.time()
    test = set_as_top(test)
    test.run()

    print "Elapsed time: ", time.time()-tt, "seconds"

    print 'result = ', test.summer.total
    print '(x, y) = (%s, %s)' % (test.x, test.y)
    print 'fs = %s' % test.fs
    print test.fs
    # for i in range(0, len(a_vals)):
    #     exec('print test.q_%d' % i)
```

---

### Further example

This example does a better job of showing what causes the error. The following script runs in serial or parallel for the default driver but fails when using both the SLSLQPdriver and pyOptDriver with SNOPT. The errors are as follows:

Using SLSQPdriver(): `AttributeError: 'SerialSystem' object has no attribute 'options'`

Using pyOptDriver() with SNOPT: `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0`

The result should be y* = 0 at x* = [0, 0, 0].

*edit: I am now getting a different error for SNOPT: `IOError: Failed to properly open SNOPT_print.out, ierror =  17`. I'm not sure what changed*

```
import numpy as np
import time

from openmdao.main.api import Component, Assembly
from openmdao.lib.datatypes.api import Float, Array
from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import FixedPointIterator, SLSQPdriver, COBYLAdriver
from pyopt_driver.pyopt_driver import pyOptDriver

class SimpleComp(Component):

    x = Float(iotype="in")
    y = Float(iotype="out")

    def execute(self):
        # print 'print'
        print 'In SimpleComp, x = %s' % self.x
        # time.sleep(2) #slow things down to make the parallization more clear

        self.y = self.x*self.x

class Summer(Component):

    def __init__(self, size):
        super(Summer, self).__init__()

        self.size = int(size)
        for i in xrange(size):
            self.add('y_%d'%i, Float(iotype="in"))

        self.add('tot', Float(iotype="out"))

    def execute(self):
        tot = 0
        for i in xrange(self.size):
            tot += getattr(self, 'y_%d'%i)
        self.tot = tot



class Sim(Assembly):

    def __init__(self, size):
        super(Sim, self).__init__()

        # self.add('x', Array(np.zeros(size), dtype='float', iotype='in'))
        # self.add('x', Float(iotype='in'))
        for i in range(0, size):
            self.add('x_%d' % i, Float(iotype='in'))

    def configure(self):

        #you'll need one process per point

        # self.add('driver', SLSQPdriver())
        self.add('driver', pyOptDriver())
        self.driver.optimizer = 'SNOPT'

        self.add('summer', Summer(size))
        # print self.x

        for i in xrange(size):
            # print 'x = ', self.x[i]
            self.add('point_%d'%i, SimpleComp())
            self.connect('x_%d' % i, 'point_%d.x' % i)
            self.connect('point_%d.y'%i, 'summer.y_%d'%i)
            self.driver.workflow.add('point_%d'%i)
            self.driver.add_parameter('x_%d' % i, high=10, low=-10)

        self.driver.workflow.add('summer')

        self.driver.add_objective('summer.tot')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from openmdao.main.api import set_as_top

    size = 3

    x = np.arange(0, size)
    # x = 1.
    print x

    sim = set_as_top(Sim(size))

    for i in range(0, size):
        exec('sim.x_%d = x[%d]' % (i, i))
    st = time.time()
    sim.run()

    print "runtime: ", time.time() - st

    print 'y* = %s' % sim.summer.tot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ran your model and saw the same things that you did. I have since been able to get it to successfully run in parallel with the following changes (my modified code is below).

1. Finite Difference of components doesn't seem to be supported under MPI. In particular, letting it divide up the model into chunks for finite-differencing caused some odd errors in parallel. There are two ways around this. I chose to define analytic derivatives for the `SimpleComp` and `Summer` components, since they were easy. You could also set `driver.gradient_options.force_fd` to True to finite difference the entire model.
2. Originally you were using PyOptDriver, but that driver doesn't work in parallel for some optimizers. Specifically, SNOPT writes out a text file, so the `ioError` that you saw was when all 3 processes were trying to write to the same file and couldn't. We have a parallel version of the PyOptDriver (called mdolab-pyoptsparse), which is what I used. The OpenMDAO wrapper is tucked away in the pyMission repository:

   https://github.com/OpenMDAO-Plugins/pyMission

   and pyoptsparse can be found here:

   https://bitbucket.org/mdolab/pyoptsparse

   When you have those, you can supply SNOPT in the proper location.
3. Finally, I needed tighter control of which components to put in parallel, so I added another level to the workflow hierarchy. The driver `parallel_stuff` contains just the SimpleComps that we want to run in parallel. Then I set the `system_type` for `driver` to serial, so that it didn't try to put anything else in the parallel group.

With those fixes, I got your model to optimize and reach (0,0,0).

```
import numpy as np
import time
from openmdao.main.api import Component, Assembly, Driver
from openmdao.lib.datatypes.api import Float, Array
from openmdao.lib.drivers.api import FixedPointIterator, SLSQPdriver, COBYLAdriver
from pyopt_driver.pyopt_driver import pyOptDriver
from pyoptsparse_driver.pyoptsparse_driver import pyOptSparseDriver

class SimpleComp(Component):
    x = Float(iotype="in")
    y = Float(iotype="out")
    def execute(self):
        # print 'print'
        print 'In SimpleComp, x = %s' % self.x
        # time.sleep(2) #slow things down to make the parallization more clear
        self.y = self.x*self.x
    def provideJ(self):
        J = np.zeros((1, 1))
        J[0][0] = 2.0*self.x
        return J
    def list_deriv_vars(self):
        return ('x', ), ('y', )

class Summer(Component):
    def __init__(self, size):
        super(Summer, self).__init__()
        self.size = int(size)
        for i in xrange(size):
            self.add('y_%d'%i, Float(iotype="in"))
        self.add('tot', Float(iotype="out"))
    def execute(self):
        tot = 0
        for i in xrange(self.size):
            tot += getattr(self, 'y_%d'%i)
        self.tot = tot
    def provideJ(self):
        J = np.ones((1, self.size))
        return J
    def list_deriv_vars(self):
        inputs = ['y_%d'%i for i in range(self.size)]
        return inputs, ('tot', )

class Sim(Assembly):
    def __init__(self, size):
        super(Sim, self).__init__()
        # self.add('x', Array(np.zeros(size), dtype='float', iotype='in'))
        # self.add('x', Float(iotype='in'))
        for i in range(0, size):
            self.add('x_%d' % i, Float(iotype='in'))
    def configure(self):
        #you'll need one process per point
        self.add('driver', pyOptSparseDriver())
        self.add('parallel_stuff', Driver())
        self.driver.optimizer = 'SNOPT'
        self.add('summer', Summer(size))
        # print self.x
        for i in xrange(size):
            # print 'x = ', self.x[i]
            self.add('point_%d'%i, SimpleComp())
            self.connect('x_%d' % i, 'point_%d.x' % i)
            self.connect('point_%d.y'%i, 'summer.y_%d'%i)
            self.parallel_stuff.workflow.add('point_%d'%i)
            self.driver.add_parameter('x_%d' % i, high=10, low=-10)
        self.driver.workflow.add(['parallel_stuff', 'summer'])
        self.driver.add_objective('summer.tot')

        # Don't try to parallelize anything except 'parallel_stuff'
        self.driver.system_type = 'serial'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from openmdao.main.api import set_as_top
    size = 2
    x = np.arange(0, size)
    # x = 1.
    print x
    sim = set_as_top(Sim(size))
    for i in range(0, size):
        exec('sim.x_%d = x[%d]' % (i, i))
    st = time.time()
    sim._setup()

    sim.run()
    print "runtime: ", time.time() - st
    print 'y* = %s' % sim.summer.tot
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this information has been very helpful.